# why I got undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym' even though I had added -ldl?

Tags: linux, undefined-reference

why I got undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym' even though I had added -ldl.It complainted on ubuntu 16.04 as it's ok on the centos.The libdl.so.2 is exist on the ubuntu at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

Comment: Perhaps `/lib` is not in the search path. You can try adding `-L/lib` after `-ldl` when you compile your program.

Comment: @colelemonz Not work...In fact I had tried to use the full path of libdl.so

Comment: Which version? One requires `#define _GNU_SOURCE` (`dlvsym`), you are good without it with `dlsym`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin version of libdl.so.2 is 2.23.I am not using dlsym but it is used in .so that I don't have source code.

Comment: I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607130/undefined-reference-to-dlsym-and-dlopen?rq=1) and thanks for your help!