# How to fix `undefined reference to dlopen` in CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake

Error:

```
 Linking CXX executable cmakeproject
 CMakeFiles/cmakeproject.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
 main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `dlopen'
 main.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `dlclose'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[2]: *** [testlink] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmakeproject.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I ask how to fix this in CMake Project because there are multiple questions like this and answers but CMake is not used by them:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/956698/13545849
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20419191/13545849
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33035858/13545849
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6183935/13545849
- ... And a lot of other "duplicates"

How to fix this if I use CMake?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have seen that answer when I was trying to fix this error. But that answer is too much generay to help me understand how to fix `undefined reference to dlopen`. My answer gives an instruction and helps to understand how I have found the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Link `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}` to your `target`

```
target_link_libraries(<target> ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

### How you could find solution

If you google `dlopen` and scroll a little you possibly will be able to find [`CMAKE_DL_LIBS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_DL_LIBS.html) page in [CMake](https://cmake.org/) documentation

> ### `CMAKE_DL_LIBS`
>
> Name of library containing `dlopen` and `dlclose`.
>
> The name of the library that has `dlopen` and `dlclose` in it, usually
> `-ldl` on most UNIX machines.