# How to make gcc generate information for gprof?

Tags: c, gcc, gprof

I know that I should use `-pg` switch and run compiled program but it is not working. I am playing with cpuminer source code to learn something about Intel intrinsics and vectorization rather than for coins. What to know where cpuminer spends most of run time. I added -pg switch to CFLAGS before I ran configure. I can see that gcc uses it during compilation e.g.:

```
    gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -pthread -maes -Wall -O0 -g -pg -MT crypto/minerd-c_blake256.o -MD -MP -MF crypto/.deps/minerd-c_blake256.Tpo -c -o crypto/minerd-c_blake256.o `test -f 'crypto/c_blake256.c' || echo './'`crypto/c_blake256.c
```

But when I run exec no `gmon.out` file appears.

Could you prompt me where should I check/look?

Just read somewhere that `gmon.out` is written when the program stops running. But mine never stops. I am killing it with ^C - maybe it prevents `gmon.out` from being written? Is there a better way to stop the program in such a way `gmon.out` will be written?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:
[Saving gmon.out before killing a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205543/saving-gmon-out-before-killing-a-process)

Works perfectly for me as well. Thanks everyone.