# How to run gprof on non-terminating multi-threaded C++ program?

Tags: c++, gprof

I can't call `std::exit` from an arbitrary thread (or via a signal handler), because other still-running threads will experience undefined behavior (typically, a segfault).

Normally, to exit the program, I would use `std::quick_exit`, but that doesn't produce the `gmon.out` file.

So is there a way to produce the `gmon.out` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205543/saving-gmon-out-before-killing-a-process solve your problem?

Comment: I thought that would not work because `_mcleanup` is not thread-safe, or at least, cannot be run concurrently with threads being profiled.

Comment: Did you try it?  Also, consider halting your process except for the main thread, and then doing that cleanup.  When I do something similar, I'll often have 2 threads working on the problem; one is attempting to make progress, the other is waking up other threads until the first one can make progress then halting them.  The goal is to get the other threads to *not* be blocking in (say) a malloc mutex.  It doesn't always work, but so long as it usually works it is good enough for debugging.